# Use css/scss variable in React component as inline style

Tags: css, reactjs, variables, styles, inline

Is there a valid way to use SCSS or CSS variable in React component as inline style?

I would like to do something like this below

**scss**

```
$red: #F65959;


:root {
  --red: $red;    
}
```

**js**

```
const style = {
  color: '--red',
};

export default style;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be like this if you want to use [css custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)

```
:root {
  --red: #{$red};
}
const style = {
  color: 'var(--red)',
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It is working, but you need to give the variable to `var()` if you want to use it in the inlined styles.

**Example**

```js
function App() {
  const style = {
    color: "var(--red)"
  };
  return <div style={style}>Foo</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
:root {
  --red: #F65959;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```